# Does K8S container use file cache of host os

Tags: memory, kubernetes, jvm-hotspot

Sorry for my poor english.

I'm tuning java vm that work in k8s pod.

Normally java vm shouldn't use all memory. Some memory should used by kernel for cache, buffer, resource management and so on.
I knew container share host os kernel. 
The question is Does resource limit of pods include kernel memory such as file cache.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, those kinds of buffers are not tracked per process and so are not bound by cgroups settings. I think the vfs cache specifically is shared globally after namespace processing but not 100% sure.

Comment: I have tried set heap use all memory.
It got the best performance. So I believe you are right.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the question you asked, I assumed you have searched about how to setup limitation for Memory in K8S ->  `https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run`

In this section you will know the limitation you set would be convert to docker command(if you use docker in k8s), `spec.containers[].resources.limits.memory` -> `--memory=""`

and if you check the official document about kernel memory in docker -> `https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#--kernel-memory-details` which hasnt mentioned in k8s document. So I assume the value should be the default value for different type of linux system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I don't know should I keep free memory for file cache in container.
As for jvm, should I set -Xmx nearly resoruces.limits.memory.